# Matlab: How to stop matlab from showing GlobalSearch info?

Tags: matlab

I am doing a multiple globalsearch in series.
Matlab shows the GlobalSearch steps each time:

> GlobalSearch stopped because it analyzed all the trial points.
>
> All 2 local solver runs converged with a positive local solver exit
>   flag.

Is there any way to stop it from displaying these info while doing the calculation? thanks.

======

## EDIT:

```
c = Cp(u,T);
opts = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','interior-point');
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','objective',...
 c,'x0',[0 0],'lb',[-Inf,-Inf],'ub',[Inf,Inf],'options',opts);
gs = GlobalSearch;
[xc,fc] = run(gs,problem);
```

Comment: Maybe a semicolon after the statement?  Can we see the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you need is:

```
c = Cp(u,T);
opts = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','interior-point','Display','off');
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','objective',...
 c,'x0',[0 0],'lb',[-Inf,-Inf],'ub',[Inf,Inf],'options',opts);
gs = GlobalSearch('Display','off');
[xc,fc] = run(gs,problem);
```

For global search and multi start you need to set display off directly in the object, whereas for the usual cases it is sufficient to set it off via *optimoptions*.

Sources: [1](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7736316),[2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/how-globalsearch-and-multistart-work.html),[3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/iterative-display.html).